# How a Dialog window can modify JS in the parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that opens a dialog. In that dialog I want to be able to modify a JS value in the parent window. The sites are at the same domain.

in the parent I can do:

```
currentUserModel.guest(false)
```

In the dialog, how can I do currentUserModel.guest(false)?

Right now if I try I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: currentUserModel is not defined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
opener.currentUserModel.guest(false)
```

Should work if the "dialog" is a window opened using `window.open()`
(It's not clear what kind of object your dialog is.)